# Let the operator $T:\mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}^n$ be defined by $Tx=(x_1+ix_2,x_1-ix_2)$ find $T^*$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let the operator $T:\mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}^n$ be defined by $Tx=(x_1+ix_2,x_1-ix_2)$ find $T^*$

how to find this I have no idea can you some help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T$ has the matrix representation

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & i\\1 & -i\end{pmatrix} $.

Thus $T^*$ has the matrix representation $A^H=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\-i & i\end{pmatrix} $.

This gives $T^*x=(x_1+x_2,-ix_1+ix_2)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By the definition of the adjoint, you should for any $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^2$ have
$$ \left\langle \begin{pmatrix}x_1+ix_2\\x_1-ix_2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix} \right\rangle = \langle Tx, y \rangle = \langle x, T^*y \rangle
= \left\langle \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}T^*_{11}y_1+T^*_{12}y_2\\T^*_{21}y_1+T^*_{22}y_2\end{pmatrix} \right\rangle.  $$
Can you choose $x$ and $y$ in a wise way in order to find the entries $T^*_{nm}$?

Comment: ...sorry not understand how can we choose those

Comment: @learner Try taking $x=y=(1,0)$ or $x=y=(0,1)$ or a combination of the two.